# In Django, how to retrieve user's selection from database?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Django project.

I have two webpages. The first one will provide a user some major programs and the user will only choose one program. Then, the second webpage will provide the user some courses to choose which are based on what program the user select in the webpage.

And here is my view.py. This function is used for the first webpage.

```
def choose_major(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MajorForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            major_program = request.GET["major_program"]
            major_obj = Major.objects.get(major=major_program)
            major_obj.save()
    return render(request, "major.html", {"form":form})
```

My question is: how to retrieve the value of variable major_program outside the function choose_major?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Save the user's choice somewhere (probably in a database or in the session), then fetch it wherever you like.  Of course you'll have to ensure you only fetch it **after** the user has successfully filled out the form.

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible for me to open the webpage in Linux before somebody fills out the form? Otherwise, I won't have the chance to check the webpage.

Comment: If they haven't filled out the form yet, there won't **be** any value for major_program, would there?  Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: So when I finish typing the code to retrieve the value of major_program outside function choose_major, and try to open the webpage in Linux, there occurs an error: list index out of range, which stop me from checking the webpage where user can select a major program.

Answer (score 0):

So when you get this variable from the request, do this to save it:

```
major_program = request.GET["major_program"]
# You probably want to do this instead
new_major = Major(major=major_program)
new_major.save()
```

This way you create a new Major object and save in the database. You would query the db to retrieve it outside of this function.

Also, since you have validated the form, instead of using

```
request.GET["major_program"]
```

you can probably use

```
form.cleaned_data["major_program]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. By query, do you mean Major.objects.all( )?

Comment: That will give you all Major objects that are saved in the db, yes. I don't know what your Major model looks like, but you can store other things there as well (like the user) and then be able to make more specific queries.

Comment: This answer creates an arbitrary Major object, but does not link it to the specific user, which was probably desired.

Comment: There is only one attribute "major" in my Major model. So if I want to retrieve the value of major_program, can I use: Major.objects.all()[0].major ?

Comment: But you probably want there to be more than one major eventually, right? So you would likely need to find a way to store users and majors together, and be able to user a query to find the major for a specific user. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: No, each time a user will only choose one major program in the first webpage, and I want to store the user's selection in the database so that when I write code for a function in view.py, I can retrieve the user's selection from database to give the user some choices in the second webpage.